# Evitar ejecución de código JavaScript se detenga por error

Tags: javascript, try-catch

tengo un problema, en un bloque de instrucciones JavaScript que se encuentra de la manera que describo abajo, estoy tratando de controlar los errores en ejecución, el detalle es que cuando ocurre una excepción, suponiendo que en la intrucción1 ocurre un error, entonces sale inmediatamente del bloque try y se ejecuta el catch, entiendo que es la función de try..catch, pero me gustaría que en lugar de salir del bloque, si ocurriera un error en instrucción1, continuara a la siguiente intrucción y así sucesivamente. Es posible eso?

```
try{
instruccion1
instruccion2
instruccion...n
}catch{
salida para errores.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un poco complicado de explicar...

En realidad cuando ejecutas un programa, existe un flujo de secuencias de instrucciones en la que si se detecta algún error en alguna instrucción el error es creado con el objeto "Error"  **DE FORMA AUTOMÁTICA**, para evitar que se sigan ejecutando instrucciones y en base a este error se puedan dar anomalías que afecten al programa.

*Imagínate que las instrucciones que siguen después del error dependan de esa misma instrucción que lo haya ocasionado.*

En el mejor de los casos terminarías de ejecutar todas las instrucciones pero con muchas anomalías.

En el peor tendrías un error nuevo, y en base a este error, otro error, y otro, y otro... etc...

Seria un caos.

---

Respecto a tu pregunta: Es posible eso?

Si tuviéramos, que trabajar de cierta forma para que continúen con las demás instrucciones, podríamos considerar algunas particularidades(**como por ejemplo que sepas exactamente que linea es la que probablemente pueda ocasionarte el error**).

Bueno, como sabrás en **try** se ejecutan las instrucciones, en **catch** se ejecutan las instrucciones si es que falla el código en alguna parte del **try**. Ahora si necesitas ejecutar algunas lineas de código en especificas podrías usarlo dentro del mismo catch:

```
try{
    instrucción 1;
    instrucción 2; //posible error
    instrucción 3;
    instrucción 4;
}
catch(error){
    instrucción 3;// las mismas del try
    instrucción 4;
}
```

o también si no lo usas en el catch podrías usarlo en el

```
finally{

}
```

De hecho es mas fácil lanzar un nuevo error personalizado con throw que andar evitándolos.